# Grouping items onto the same line to avoid wrapping

Tags: grouping, inline, wrap

I am authoring a poker-related document and am using the following commands to allow me to display cards:

```
% Suit image adjustments:
\newcommand{\suit}[1]{\includegraphics[width=8pt, height=8pt]{#1}}

% Commands to display suit only.
\newcommand{\heart}{\suit{../res/heart_26x26.png}}
\newcommand{\club}{\suit{../res/club_26x26.png}}
\newcommand{\spade}{\suit{../res/spade_26x26.png}}
\newcommand{\daimond}{\suit{../res/daimond_26x26.png}}

% Commands to display both rank and suit.
\newcommand{\ofheart}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1} \heart}
\newcommand{\ofclub}[1]{\textcolor{black}{#1} \club}
\newcommand{\ofspade}[1]{\textcolor{black}{#1} \spade}
\newcommand{\ofdaimond}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1} \daimond}
```

This works as intended and I am pleased with the results -- however, when cards get wrapped onto a new line I sometimes find that [ranks get separated from their suits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz0dF.png).

Is there any way to "group" items so that they get wrapped onto new lines together?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Not sure I understand but perhaps using an `\mbox{}` to keep things together: `\newcommand{\ofheart}[1]{\mbox{\textcolor{red}{#1} \heart}}`?

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: `\newcommand{\ofheart}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}~\heart}` should do.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks for the kind welcome.  I will endeavor to provide a complete code snippet in the future.  Your suggestion works; now I the ranks and suits of the same cards stay together (see http://i.imgur.com/D4oOnO5.png).

Comment: A suggestion: Use a small space (e.g. `\,` which never breaks); yes, the spacing will be different (intentionally) but in your example it is already hard to notice whether the symbol comes before or after the digit/letter. By the way, there are fonts that include ♣, ♠, ♥ and ♦ already (`libertine` does).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: @Jubobs - In all honesty the answer I used (and the first answer that was given) was in a comment above this one and so I was reluctant to give the "tick" to your answer.  I take on board your points however, and will tick yours as it is indeed a valid answer.

Comment: @JimmidyJoo I didn't mean to pressure you into accepting my answer. I merely want to keep the place tidy :) If you're satisfied with an answer left as a comment by another poster, ask him/her to make it a full-blown answer that you can accept (you can then "unaccept" my answer and accept his/her).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using existing symbols rather than images for the suits. Then you can simply use a non-breaking space `~` (EDIT: or, even better, a thinspace `\,` which is non-breaking as well, as suggested by @Qrrbrbirlbel) to avoid line breaking between rank and suit.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{arev}

\DeclareSymbolFont{extraup}{U}{zavm}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varheart}{\mathalpha}{extraup}{86}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vardiamond}{\mathalpha}{extraup}{87}

\newcommand\ofheart[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1\,$\varheart$}}
\newcommand\ofclub[1]{\textcolor{black}{#1\,$\clubsuit$}}
\newcommand\ofspade[1]{\textcolor{black}{#1\,$\spadesuit$}}
\newcommand\ofdiamond[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1\,$\vardiamond$}}

\begin{document}

\ofclub{3} \qquad \ofspade{K} \qquad \ofheart{Q} \qquad \ofdiamond{4}

\end{document}
```